# How to select a value, then calculate few functions on it?

Tags: sql

For example:

```
Select count(.....) as my_val, my_val / 2 as half, my_val*2 as doubleit from table
```

i want to use the value from the count to calculate more values and return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name an expression if you place it in a subquery. For example:

```
select my_val, my_val / 2 as half, my_val * 2 as doubleit
from (
  select count(.....) as my_val from table
) x
```

Or with a CTE:

```
with q as (select count(.....) as my_val from table)
select my_val, my_val / 2 as half, my_val * 2 as doubleit from q
```